# ansible: local test new module with Error:Module unable to decode valid JSON on stdin. Unable to figure out what parameters were passed

Tags: python, ansible

I'm new to Python. This is my first Ansible module in order to delete the SimpleDB domain from ChaosMonkey deletion.

When tested in my local `venv` with my Mac OS X, it keeps saying

> Module unable to decode valid JSON on stdin.  Unable to figure out
>   what parameters were passed.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Delete SimpleDB Domain

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
import boto3

def delete_sdb_domain():

    fields = dict(
           sdb_domain_name=dict(required=True, type='str')
    )

    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=fields)

    client = boto3.client('sdb')

    response = client.delete_domain(DomainName='module.params['sdb_domain_name']')  

    module.exit_json(changed = False, meta = response)


def main():

    delete_sdb_domain()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I'm trying to pass in parameters from this file: `/tmp/args.json`.

and run the following command to make the local test:

```
$ python ./delete_sdb_domain.py /tmp/args.json
```

please note I'm using venv test environment on my Mac.

If you find any syntax error in my module, please also point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should test your modules.
`AnsibleModule` expects to have specific JSON as stdin data.

So the closest thing you can try is:

```
python ./delete_sdb_domain.py < /tmp/args.json
```

But I bet you have your json file in wrong format (no `ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS`, etc.).

To debug your modules you can use `test-module` script from [Ansible hacking pack](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/hacking):

```
./hacking/test-module -m delete_sdb_domain.py -a "sdb_domain_name=zzz"
```

Comment: I did follow the instruction from Ansible for that args.json file and ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS is there.                                                              {
    "ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {
         "delete_sdb_domain": "whyislikethis",
    }
}

Comment: and tried python ./delete_sdb_domain.py < /tmp/args.json this command and same error as before.

Comment: ./hacking/test-module -m delete_sdb_domain.py -a "sdb_domain_name=zzz"    is working I think and got some RAW OUTPUT and INVALID OUTPUT FORMAT

Comment: can't past out here as it's over the comment limit.

Comment: ensure that you have **only** json object as output and no debug output from boto or something else.

Comment: thanks Konstantin.  I've removed response and last line, so that JSON on stdin error gone! but got a Syntax error: File "<unknown>", line 18
    client.delete_domain(DomainName='module.params['sdb_domain_name']',)
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax